# Tooltip not working in chrome and ie

Tags: php, javascript, tooltip

my site is using a tool tip from http://boxover.swazz.org (website is not currenly available)

the url of my site is http://dcbookshop.net/

the tool tip is working fine for english but making problem for malayalam (its a language)

it is ok in mozila but ie and chrome shows the text on bottom of the screen.

To test yourself.

1. Go to url http://dcbookshop.net/  (in ie or chrome)
2. Put your mouse over the book cover of **pachaviral** (in **best sellers**, with a old women as cover)
3. now look at bottom of the screen. you will see the text in malayalam which is supposed to be shown in the tool tip box
4. The tool tip is workin fine for english (to test that put your mouse over AMEN in DC TOP 10)

Comment: Your website's code has *lots* of errors, you may want to fix them before: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://dcbookshop.net/ .

Comment: i will do it as soon as possile, thank u for ur comment

Comment: Just wanted to say I really admire how you take criticism. Have a happy new year!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the paragraph tags from the title and it should work

Comment: It actually works! which is a miracle.I might just add that having html code within a `title` attribute is going to give you alot of problems in the future(such as this). Try using pure javascript to store the code.

Comment: @digitalFresh thank u for ur comment. i will use javascript in my next project instead of html in title tag

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not valid XHTML 1.0:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdcbookshop.net%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Most of the 80 errors should not be specially relevant to this problem, but having `<br />` tags inside an attributes seems to annoy the rendering engine.

In general, the first step to avoid cross-browser issues when manipulating the DOM tree from JavaScript and styling with CSS is to provide rock-solid valid HTML so the resulting DOM does not vary. Otherwise, browsers need to figure out how to fix invalid HTML and they don't always do it the same exact way.